# Just installed ubuntu 14.04 but after restart it wont boot neither windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I used a live USB to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7 the installation went fine but when I restarted the computer Ubuntu wouldn't boot from my HDD,neither windows. instead it came up with try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu so I restarted without the live usb plugged in and I got an error message 'Reboot and select a proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press any key.'

I read a lot of posts about people that had similar problems but so far none of the solutions that worked for them have worked for me.

I also ran boot-repair but that didn't fix the problem either.

Here is the link from boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/15211262/
Please any help would be appreciated.

My laptop is a hp pavillion g6 intel i3 processor

Answer (score 0):

This one

> Reboot and select a proper boot device or insert boot media in
>   selected boot device and press any key.

sounds for me like a message from the BIOS not finding any boot device.

Did you install grub? The pasted snippet says "no grub" for all partitions (~lines 266). You may try the grub repair instructions mentioned in this answer: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Wubi which is not supported. May i suggest you try using [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to install Ubuntu.

Moreover you are using Windows 7 which is ready for free upgrade to Windows 10. Do you want to upgrade it Windows 10 and then give it a try.

Moreover look for this message in your pastebin

```
Error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/sda3 --
Device or resource busy.  This means Linux won't know about any changes you made
to /dev/sda3 until you reboot -- so you shouldn't mount it or use it in any way
before rebooting.
```

Linux has got issues in terms of this partition.

Once you follow the other method to install linux try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```